# When the value can either be dollar or percent for the same field which field type should I use in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario where I want to store dollar amounts or percentages in the same field in SqlServer.

I have a Type field which takes a value such as 'dollar' or 'percent' and then a value field which takes either type of value: 25.00 or 0.05.

If this is a terrible idea I would like to know, because then I will split the fields out.

Should I be using decimal or float for this type of field and why?

Comment: Use `numeric`/`decimal`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. There is no datatype called NumericDecimal in sqlserver. Do you mean Numeric(18,0) or Decimal(18,0)?

Comment: Have two different columns, one for amounts and one for percentages. Perhaps decimal(10,2), if you want two decimals.

Comment: Why would you *not* want to split these clearly different things into different columns? How are you going to tell if 0.05 is 5% or 5 cents? (And might this be a case where the `money` type would be best for the dollar amounts?)

Comment: Well, a percent can be like .0004 but dollars+cents are generally 2 decimal places. So you'd have to have like decimal(10,4) or similar to hold both.

Comment: Also, just from a design perspective, I'm not a fan of not knowing what the value is (dollar or percent) without having to check a different column that tells me a type. We have some data like that, and in the grand scheme of things, it sucks for complex queries and operations.

Comment: @MattGibson that's why I have a Type field also.

Comment: You also need to consider what you need to do with the data. If you're ever going to, say, sum the money (but not the percentage) the code will be cleaner and faster if it's in a separate column. (I can't quite see an advantage to trying to mash two different facts into one column, myself.)

Comment: @Nikki9696 This is very true, but wouldn't complex queries also suck without a Type and 2 separate columns?

Comment: Not as much, no.  =)

Comment: It's two different pieces of information (percent or money), so I'm assuming any queries beyond simple CRUD won't do the same thing with the data, so they'd all need like CASE WHEN COLUMN1='DOLLAR' AND... or some icky thing like that - and if your DB is normalized, the type name is stored in a different table and you use an id, which then needs extra joins.

Comment: What is the impetus for having both "types" in the same column?  You're using a separate column to define what's in it, so why not just have two fields with names that identity what's in the field???

Comment: I do get the desire to design like this, as one column would always be empty if the other has a value, which can also seem silly. It really depends on what you think the complexity level will be in the future, which can be hard to determine now. I'd just have to say that 2 different columns might prevent some swearing in the future, but just one column might be simpler for small apps and to start with.

Comment: I am starting to see what you guys are saying, why not just play it safe! Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a terrible idea I would like to know, because then I will split the fields out.

```
All depends on your design but not a terribe thing. Even if you split the columns at any point of time one column would be filled but the other column should be 0 or Null.
```

Should I be using decimal or float for this type of field and why?

```
Use can use Decimal refer the example below.

Declare @table table (
    Type VARCHAR(50)
    ,Value DECIMAL(18, 2)
    )

Insert into @table
values ('$',25.00),
('%',0.05),
('$',25.00)
```

You can do sum or average using

```
SELECT sum(value) AS Sum
    ,avg(value) AS Avg
FROM @table
WHERE type = '$'
```